# adding additional data with https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add additional form data with each upload.

I am using this right now.

```
var data = {
    formData : {
        vendor:    '{{ $vendor }}',
        extension: '{{ $extension }}'
    },
    acceptFileTypes: /^({{ str_replace('/', '\/', implode('|', $mimes)) }})$/i,
    uploadTemplateId: 'media-upload-template-{{$identifier}}',
    downloadTemplateId: 'media-download-template-{{$identifier}}',

    // jQuery plugin requires size in Bytes, Laravel uses KB
    maxFileSize: {{ ($_valid = (int) $max_file_size) ? $_valid * 1024 : 'undefined' }}
}

// Grab the CSRF data
if ((csrf = $('#media-upload-csrf-{{$identifier}}')) && csrf.length) {
    data.formData[csrf.attr('name')] = csrf.val();
}

$('#media-upload-{{$identifier}}').fileupload(data);

$('#media-upload-{{$identifier}}').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    if (inputs.filter('[required][value=""]').first().focus().length) {
        return false;
    }
    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();

});
```

I am adding a user id to each file, so userid[] would equal n, this comes from a select right next to the file in the upload template

The problem comes in when using

```
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
```

It overwrites all of my settings in the data variable above.

I also tried using

```
$.each(inputs.serializeArray(), function(i, obj) {
            data.formData[obj.name] =obj.value;
});
```

in place of

```
data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
```

with no such luck.

Any ideas?